# An application for MySQL query that can be used without code

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner to database and MySQL and I planned to build an application using MySQL to practice what I have learned. This is what I expect my application to do:

1. Users can upload their CSV files (e.g. contract files).
2. Users can search for a specific column value to get all files that contain that column value (e.g. search for all contract files that has date 01/01/2017), without typing the code. For example, there will be some drop down menu where you can choose the filter value, and when you press the search button, the relevant files will come out.
3. Users can do aggregation and analysis on the uploaded file (e.g. the number of contracts made in past 3 years).

I'm not sure if I should make it a desktop app or web app, and what other skills I should learn except for MySQL. I would really appreciate it if you could give me some suggestions on this, or in general about the application.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow because it's too broad and too opinion-driven for our format.You might try https://programmers.stackexchange.com/  Besides MySQL, what programming environment can you use? Dotnet, Java, php, node, swift, what?  To choose between a desktop or web app you'll need to consider your environment. If your goal is purely learning, web app skills are probably more valuable.

Comment: If users are going to do their own analysis you might as let them use something they are used to like excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is to create your idea using php and mysqli, link to the database and insert, retrieve or update any idea of your choice. Also HTML is a necessity.